# Javascript Function in head is undefined in body

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an HTML application that opens a new window that contains a Summary Report and gives the option to print that window. This new window is generated dynamically, but I have put a copy of typical results at [electioncalc.com/WhyIsThisADud.html](http://electioncalc.com/WhyIsThisADud.html)

Problem is the "printThis()" function defined in the head is not recognized in the body. When I click the Print Button, I get "printThis unknown object" or an "Object Expected" error. I put in a dummy "printThis2()" function that had no content at all. It was not recognized in the body either. I must have made a really basic error here, but I sure can't find it. The HTML code always verifies fine. I have no idea if the javascript function works. I got it online, but haven't been able to run it because of this issue.

Code Sections:

```
<script type="/text/javascript"> 
/* <![CDATA[ */
  function printThis()   {
    var a = window.open('','', scrollbars=yes, width=800, height=600);
    a.document.open("text/html");
   a.document.write(document.getElementById('printableContent').innerHTML);
    a.document.close();
    a.print();
  }
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

... in the head, and in the body ...

```
<div id="printDiv">
  <input type="button" value=" Print " id="printButton" onClick="Javascript: printThis()">
</div>
```

I have done websites and applications for years, but I have never come across something like this. Any help (or even a direction to go) would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe remove the leading slash from `type="/text/javascript"`...

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="/text/javascript"> 
              ^
              |
```

Your browser probably doesn't identify your code as being javascript because of this bad `type` attribute (remove the leading slash).

Answer (score 1):

The actual error you should get should be self-explanatory:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: **yes is not defined**

Because the [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) function takes three **string** params, like so:

```
window.open('','', 'scrollbars=yes, width=800, height=600');
```

Currently your Javascript is executing `scrollbars=yes` as a statement, attempting to assign the variable `yes` to a global `scrollbars` variable. Since that variable doesn't exist, you get an error.

Comment: +1 since this is obviously enough to break things, but to me it doesn't sound like the problem described in the question.

Comment: Also, would you really get that error? I'd think a syntax error would be more likely, and that the interpreter would not even try to execute the `scrollbars=yes` assignment (unless this is ES6 and it has support for default argument values).

Comment: Absolutely. The engine will execute `scrollbars=yes, width=800, height=600` as a Javascript statement as the result of that could have been a string. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mwzs2f15/

Comment: Ah, of course! Sorry for my confusion and thanks for taking the time to enlighten me. Now I also realize that my thoughts about default arguments doesn't apply to the situation at all, as that's about function declarations and not invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys ... both of those are right.  First problem was I had a flakey script type with a leading slash "/text/javascript". That's why the function wasn't recognized. Shoulda caught that.

And as written the function "window.open" looks like it takes 5 parameters. Shoulda checked the script more carefully before I cut and paste. With appropriate quote marks, all works well.

Much appreciation.